# How to add source file (.cs) as an embedded resource of the built DLL

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a .NET 5 project (using the SDK-style project format). My requirement is that I need to load the source code of a C# class at runtime (as an embedded resource), but I need said source file to also be checked for compiler errors when I build the solution and offer IntelliSense in Visual Studio.

Setting the file's Build Action to "Embedded resource" in the file's properties makes it so that the file is no longer regarded as a source file, so that it is no longer built, and IntelliSense is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to set the file's Build Action property to "Embedded resource" and then edit the project's .csproj file. In that file an `<EmbeddedResource>` XML element will have been added for the file, as well as a `<Compile Remove="">` element. Remove the `<Compile Remove="">` element. The file will still be embedded into the project's DLL for loading as an embedded resource, and will also be handled as a regular .cs source file.